# Использовать ли React.js для работы с API или и так сойдёт?

Tags: php, javascript, reactjs, render

Имеем:

- API, наподобие VK, которому посылаем запрос на js, приходит ответ в виде jsonp.
- При этом не всегда получается схема: пришел ответ - распарсил - вставил. Иногда нужно предварительно обработать данные, возможно сгруппировать, чуть отфильтровать по определенному признаку и т.д.
- Также расчет на то, что сайтом, использующим API будут пользоваться и на мобильных устройствах тоже (то есть типа они послабее стационарных)

Соответственно как быть?
Говорят, что до сих пор рендеринг силами серверной стороны быстрее, нежели средствами клиента. С другой стороны, если бы это было так, то всякие ангуляры и реакты не использовались бы...

Вот несколько вариантов вывода:

1. Ответ шлем в php-файл (контроллер->view) и там распихиваем что куда надо

```html
<div id="users-wrap">
    <div class="user">
        Photo: <div class="user-photo"><?= $user['photo']; ?></div>
        Name: <div class="user-name"><?= $user['name']; ?></div>
        Age: <div class="user-age"><?= $user['age']; ?></div>
        
        favorite:
        Books: <div class="favorite-books"><?= $user['books']; ?></div>
        Videos: <div class="favorite-videos"><?= $user['videos']; ?></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

2. Похлеще. Также ответ шлем в `php` и там:

```html
<?php

echo '<div id="users-wrap">
    <div class="user">
        Photo: <div class="user-photo">'. $user['photo']; .'</div>
        Name: <div class="user-name">'. $user['name']; .'</div>
        Age: <div class="user-age">'. $user['age']; .'</div>
        
        favorite:
        Books: <div class="favorite-books">'. $user['books']; .'</div>
        Videos: <div class="favorite-videos">'. $user['videos']; .'</div>
    </div>  
</div>';

?>
```

3. React.js

```html
var User = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="user">
  Photo: <div class="user-photo">{this.props.photo}</div>
  Name: <div class="user-name">{this.props.name}</div>
        Age: <div class="user-age">{this.props.age}</div>
        
        favorite:
        Books: <div class="favorite-books">{this.props.books}</div>
        Videos: <div class="favorite-videos">{this.props.videos}</div>        
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var UserList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var userNodes = this.props.data.map(function(user) {
      return (
        <User name={user.name} key={user.id} age={user.age} photo={user.photo} books={user.books} videos={user.videos}></User>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {userNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserList data={users} />,
  document.getElementById('users-wrap')
);
```

где `{users}` это данные, которые прилетят с запроса

4. Гибрид react + php (еще что-то бессмысленное). Еще не придумал как-тут осуществить `foreach` в концепции реакта, чтоб в итоге получилось типа такого:

```html
<?php foreach ($users as $user):  ?>

var User = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="user">
  Photo: <div class="user-photo"><?= $user['photo']; ?></div>
  Name: <div class="user-name"><?= $user['name']; ?></div>
        Age: <div class="user-age"><?= $user['age']; ?></div>
        
        favorite:
        Books: <div class="favorite-books"><?= $user['books']; ?></div>
        Videos: <div class="favorite-videos"><?= $user['videos']; ?></div>        
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <User data={users} />
);

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Но воспалённый мозг может в итоге на многое...

5. Еще какой-нибудь вариант

---

Если вы дочитали до конца, проявили силу воли, то вопрос: какой вариант с учетом требований хоть как-то уместнее? Будет ли чистый react быстрее с учетом требований или можно делать 1-ым вариантом и не париться? Или еще каким-либо вариантом, который тут не описан?

Comment: Вы теплое с мягким попутали. Серверный рендеринг быстрее, но SPA выигрывают в скорости не за счет скорости рендеринга, а за счет снижения объема передаваемых по сети данных. Ну и кучи плюшек, связанных с функциональным удобством приложения. Хотите SPA -- используйте что-то из фреймворков. И да, React -- это только View в MVC (для нормальной работы с данными посмотрите в сторону flux/redux). А если не хотите SPA -- делайте все на сервере.

Comment: В 4м варианте какая-то жесть. Нужен один класс на всех User'ов, а не по классу на каждого.

Comment: Я не очень експерт, но я бы в таком случае использовал redux+react на форнте, а бекенде - апи - если там нужна делать кардинальные изменения в полученых данных(ну или делать это на фронте, но это вроде не по канону) получать данные к примеру через axios ну или fetch.
По поводу foreach, вы же передаете в компонент массив юзеров, далеее используя функцию map (это же js) формируете контент компонента в переменной, а далее рендерите все это добро.

Answer (score -1):

Зависит от того, какими ресурсами Вы распологаете. 
Вариант 2 сразу выбрасывайте. 
Собственно, если планируются большие нагрузки при возможности стеснения ресурсами, то лучше лишнюю работу повесить на клиента, чем вешать сервер шаблонизацией. 
Так что лично я голосую за вариант 3.

Comment: почему 2 вариант выбрасывать?

Comment: @Grundy а каково ваше развернутое экспертное мнение? Поделитесь?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, без разницы вообще :)

Comment: @Grundy это значит "Мне плевать" или "Все одинаково приемлемо по всем параметрам"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, тут зависит от объема данных и частоты запросов. Поэтому чтобы заметить разницу. мне кажется надо будет постараться :)