# Как организовать шаблонизацию для "бесконечной прокрутки"?

Tags: php, шаблоны, шаблонизаторы

Сразу хочу сказать, что цели делать что-то быстро и для кого-то нет, просто интересно повозится и сделать велосипед самому

Вопрос вот в чем, допустим есть файл шаблона новостей "news.tmp", на стороне сервера он обрабатывается как-то так

```
function GetTemp($tempPath, $tempVars = []) {
    extract($tempVars, EXTR_SKIP);
    ob_start();
    include $tempPath;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Т.к. в самом шаблоне дальше циклов, условий и выводов переменных дело не заходит, считаю, что это идеальный вариант который не вносит кашу типа `{{name}}` и быстрее (быстрее же?) работает, не требует установки на сервер php расширений, что не позволяют использовать дохлые хостинги

После того как на странице вывелись первые 10 новостей шаблонизированых сервером и юзер прокручивает ниже запускается автозагрузка, и тут вопрос, как получить новые новости?

1. Шаблонизировать опять же на сервере и отдать html. Но мне кажется это затратным как юзеру так и серверу
2. Отдать юзеру переменные в JSON и пусть он сам шаблонизирует на JS. И тут возникает главный вопрос, где юзер будет хранить шаблон? Подгружать "news.tmp"? Но там все намешано с php, делать на JS шаблонизатор который кушает в таком виде? Или делать 2 шаблона и поддерживать их (дикость)? Или все же сделать нормальный шаблонизатор, но будет ли он быстрее GetTemp()? А может сделать шаблонизатор который компилирует шаблон в PHP+HTML код, а после отдавать его GetTemp()?

Comment: Это далеко не самый большой потребитель ресурсов сервера, я бы не заморачивался и поставил twig (я уж не говорю о том, что в нем не надо тратить нервы на всякий isnull-проверки и прочие обычные ситуации). Рендерить однозначно либо только на сервере, либо только в js, иначе вы очень скоро будете тратить все рабочее время на разгребание шаблонизации.

Comment: `Отдать юзеру переменные в JSON и пусть он сам шаблонизирует ` ......`Но там все намешано с php,` - вы определитесь отдавать данные  или всё же намешано.... потому что не может быть намешано, если всё отдавать.................поэтому либо у вас шаблоны на сервере и рендер (говорят серверный рендер быстрее, хотя хз)......... либо шаблон на клиенте.......... вообще, как я понимаю, это всё основанно на мнениях, т.к. мой вопрос подобный http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511396/191482   закрыли xD

Comment: Может на `Go`? Ресурсов кушает мало, можно использовать дохлые сервера :D

Answer (score -1):

Я бы сделал второй вариант, в качестве шаблонизатора использовал бы *JS* библиотеку *underscore.js* там есть функция [`template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template), которая и помогает рендерить шаблон (набор *DOM*-элементов, находящийся на уже загруженной странице внутри тега `script`, например), заполняя его переменными из переданного *JSON* объекта, который можно подгрузить с сервера.